# understanding bootloader with linker

Tags: bootloader, samd21, linker-script

I'm using chip SAMD21G18
[SAM-BA bootloader](https://github.com/MicrochipTech/cryptoauth_usecase_secureboot/tree/master/SAMBA_BOOTLOADER/SAMBA_D21_BOOTLOADER1/src)
[Bossac code](https://github.com/shumatech/BOSSA/blob/master/src)

---

I'm looking at how bootloader works. but found some questions that i cant get an answer for:

looking into source code of PC client software (Bossac) that uploads the BIN file to microcontroller which has bootloader software (SAM-BA monitor).

the code initialize flash object :

```cpp
flashPtr = new D2xNvmFlash(_samba, "ATSAML21x18", 4096, 64, 0x20004000, 0x20008000) ;
```

where the class D2xNvmFlash inherited from class called Flash:

```cpp
    Flash(Samba& samba,
          const std::string& name,
          uint32_t addr,                 // Flash base address
          uint32_t pages,                // Number of pages
          uint32_t size,                 // Page size in bytes
          uint32_t planes,               // Number of flash planes
          uint32_t lockRegions,          // Number of flash lock regions
          uint32_t user,                 // Address in SRAM where the applet and buffers will be placed
          uint32_t stack);               // Address in SRAM where the applet stack will be placed
```

so from my understanding from this code:

- the bss data stored at:  0x20004000.
- stack will start at: 0x20008000 and will grow towards 0.

however, when i look into the linker script:

**linker script: -Wl,--section-start=.text=0x2000,-Tsamd21g18a_flash.ld**

```
 * \file
 *
 * \brief Linker script for running in internal FLASH on the SAMD21G18A
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2018 Microchip Technology Inc.
 *
 * \asf_license_start
 *
 * \page License
 *
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may
 * not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the Licence at
 * 
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 * 
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an AS IS BASIS, WITHOUT
 * WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 *
 * \asf_license_stop
 *
 */


OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-littlearm", "elf32-littlearm", "elf32-littlearm")
OUTPUT_ARCH(arm)
SEARCH_DIR(.)

/* Memory Spaces Definitions */
MEMORY
{
  rom      (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x00040000
  ram      (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x00008000
}

/* The stack size used by the application. NOTE: you need to adjust according to your application. */
STACK_SIZE = DEFINED(STACK_SIZE) ? STACK_SIZE : DEFINED(__stack_size__) ? __stack_size__ : 0x2000;

/* Section Definitions */
SECTIONS
{
    .text :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _sfixed = .;
        KEEP(*(.vectors .vectors.*))
        *(.text .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.*)
        *(.glue_7t) *(.glue_7)
        *(.rodata .rodata* .gnu.linkonce.r.*)
        *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*)

        /* Support C constructors, and C destructors in both user code
           and the C library. This also provides support for C++ code. */
        . = ALIGN(4);
        KEEP(*(.init))
        . = ALIGN(4);
        __preinit_array_start = .;
        KEEP (*(.preinit_array))
        __preinit_array_end = .;

        . = ALIGN(4);
        __init_array_start = .;
        KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
        KEEP (*(.init_array))
        __init_array_end = .;

        . = ALIGN(4);
        KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.ctors))
        KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o) .ctors))
        KEEP (*(SORT(.ctors.*)))
        KEEP (*crtend.o(.ctors))

        . = ALIGN(4);
        KEEP(*(.fini))

        . = ALIGN(4);
        __fini_array_start = .;
        KEEP (*(.fini_array))
        KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
        __fini_array_end = .;

        KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.dtors))
        KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o) .dtors))
        KEEP (*(SORT(.dtors.*)))
        KEEP (*crtend.o(.dtors))

        . = ALIGN(4);
        _efixed = .;            /* End of text section */
    } > rom

    /* .ARM.exidx is sorted, so has to go in its own output section.  */
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__exidx_start = .);
    .ARM.exidx :
    {
      *(.ARM.exidx* .gnu.linkonce.armexidx.*)
    } > rom
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__exidx_end = .);

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _etext = .;

    .relocate : AT (_etext)
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _srelocate = .;
        *(.ramfunc .ramfunc.*);
        *(.data .data.*);
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _erelocate = .;
    } > ram

    /* .bss section which is used for uninitialized data */
    .bss (NOLOAD) :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _sbss = . ;
        _szero = .;
        *(.bss .bss.*)
        *(COMMON)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _ebss = . ;
        _ezero = .;
    } > ram

    /* stack section */
    .stack (NOLOAD):
    {
        . = ALIGN(8);
        _sstack = .;
        . = . + STACK_SIZE;
        . = ALIGN(8);
        _estack = .;
    } > ram

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _end = . ;
}
```

from linker script and microcontroller applet i understand that  the ram starts at 0x20000000 and ends at 0x20008000

so why bossac code has set ram applet buffers at 0x20004000 ?
and how exactly the bootloader is responsible of all this address?

i thought all this initializing and addresses of stack, .bss data sections are happening when reset_handler and linker script:

**applet reset handler:**

```c
void Reset_Handler(void)
{
        uint32_t *pSrc, *pDest;

        /* Initialize the relocate segment */
        pSrc = &_etext;
        pDest = &_srelocate;

        if (pSrc != pDest) {
                for (; pDest < &_erelocate;) {
                        *pDest++ = *pSrc++;
                }
        }

        /* Clear the zero segment */
        for (pDest = &_szero; pDest < &_ezero;) {
                *pDest++ = 0;
        }

        /* Set the vector table base address */
        pSrc = (uint32_t *) & _sfixed;
        SCB->VTOR = ((uint32_t) pSrc & SCB_VTOR_TBLOFF_Msk);

        /* Change default QOS values to have the best performance and correct USB behaviour */
        SBMATRIX->SFR[SBMATRIX_SLAVE_HMCRAMC0].reg = 2;
#if defined(ID_USB)
        USB->DEVICE.QOSCTRL.bit.CQOS = 2;
        USB->DEVICE.QOSCTRL.bit.DQOS = 2;
#endif
        DMAC->QOSCTRL.bit.DQOS = 2;
        DMAC->QOSCTRL.bit.FQOS = 2;
        DMAC->QOSCTRL.bit.WRBQOS = 2;

        /* Overwriting the default value of the NVMCTRL.CTRLB.MANW bit (errata reference 13134) */
        NVMCTRL->CTRLB.bit.MANW = 1;

        /* Initialize the C library */
        __libc_init_array();

        /* Branch to main function */
        main();

        /* Infinite loop */
        while (1);
}
```

---

### edit after comments (23/12/2019):

applet code compiled and being sent to SRAM:

````
    .global start
    .global stack
    .global reset
    .global dst_addr
    .global src_addr
    .global words

    .text
    .thumb
    .align 0

start:
    ldr     r0, dst_addr
    ldr     r1, src_addr
    ldr     r2, words
    b       check

copy:
    ldmia   r1!, {r3}
    stmia   r0!, {r3}
    sub     r2, #1

check:
    cmp     r2, #0
    bne     copy

    @ Fix for SAM-BA stack bug
    ldr     r0, reset
    cmp     r0, #0
    bne     return
    ldr     r0, stack
    mov     sp, r0

return:
    bx      lr

    .align  0
stack:
    .word   0
reset:
    .word   0
dst_addr:
    .word   0
src_addr:
    .word   0
words:
    .word   0
```
````

Comment: You may be confusing two different situations.  The linker script would control the usage of memory when the code you are uploading later runs.  But the usage of memory *while the bootloader is running* may well be entirely different.

Comment: after researching and trying, you are right, but why they put "applet" stack pointer to be end of SRAM. this means that the applet with push on the "main program" data as it has same stack.. right?

Comment: i mean if the applet have push instructions it will overwrite the main program stack data

Comment: No.  A program does not have any stack data until it starts running and put something on the stack.

Comment: @ChrisStratton (there are 3 programs here) : bootloader + applet / user program .. i'm talking about applet stack overwriting bootloader stack data

Comment: because bootloader will call applet and then applet will go back to bootloader many times to write the flash